# how to perform date calculations from different tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please forgive me if this is a basic question, I'm a beginner in SQL and need some help performing date calculations from 2 tables in SQL.

I have two tables (patient and chd) they look like this:

**Patient**:

```
ID|Age|date         |Alive
--------------------------
1  50  01/09/2013      Y
2  52  11/05/2015      N
3  19  20/07/2016      N
```

**CHD**:

```
    ID|Age|indexdate        
    --------------------
    1  50  01/08/2012    
    2  52  11/11/2013    
    3  19  10/07/2015
```

The patient table contains about 500,000 records from 2010-2016 and the CHD table contains about 350,000 records from 2012-2013. What I want to do is see how many CHD patients have died from 2012-2016, and if they have died has 12months passed?

I'm not sure how to do this but I know a join is needed on the ID and we set the where condition with alive as NOT 'Y'

The final output should look like this based on the sample above:

```
ID|Age|indexdate| deathdate
---------------------------
2  52  11/11/2013 11/05/2015
3  19  10/07/2016 20/07/2016
```

Any questions let me know!

EDIT: just to make it clear, patients can appear multiple times in the patient table until they die.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that this query gets the date of death from the `patient` table:

```
select p.id, min(p.date) as deathdate
from patient p
where p.Alive = 'N'
group by p.id;
```

Then, you can get what you want with a join:

```
select count(*)
from chd c join
     (select p.id, min(p.date) as deathdate
      from patient p
      where p.Alive = 'N'
      group by p.id
     ) pd
     on c.id = pd.id;
```

You can then address your questions with a `where` clause in the outer query.  For instance:

```
where deathdate >= current_date - interval '1 year'
```

Comment: Can i ask why are you using min(p.date)? every patient dies at different date so not sure why we need min. Also, we dont check from todays date if 1 year has passed, we need to check if the difference between date(patient table) and indexdate(chd table) is > 1 year.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: @lo_iQ . . . Your question is not clear about whether patients can appear multiple times in the table.  It seems likely to me that if you have a patient state ("alive", "not alive"), then you might have multiple rows in the table for a given patient.

Comment: yes they appear multiple times. Once they die they will no longer appear.

Comment: any idea how i do this even if they appear multiple times?

Comment: please can you explain this query. Will it work for multiple patients? if i remove the min(p.date) to p.date will that compare the deathdate to indexdate? 
sorry for being annoying but would like to understand how it works and if it gives me results that I expect

Comment: @lo_iQ . . . The `group by` ensures that there is only one row per patient.