# Match records and perform date calculations within same query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This referes to a question i asked yesterday which didn't get solved. I have now simplified my tables so the question can be answered, but need some further help.

I have a table called chd18 (100,000+ records), which contains records of 18+ patients with a disease CHD.

```
ID|Age|indexdate
1  20  11/05/2013
2  25  19/10/2012
3  44  07/12/2013
4  85  01/01/2014
```

I then have another table (died1216) with all patients (500,000+ records) that have died between April 2012-March 2016

```
ID|Age|deathdate
2  25  20/10/2012
4  85  03/01/2015
```

What I want to do is create another table where I check if any of the CHD18 patients have died between April 2012-March 2016 (table died1216), if so, is the difference between indexdate and deathdate >=12  months.

Essentially that table should look like this

```
ID|Age|indexdate|deathdate
4  85  01/01/2014 03/01/2015
```

I know a join between these 2 tables are needed on the ID, but not sure how to achieve this, especially checking if 12months has passed between the 2 dates.

Please can someone kindly assist.

**For anyone saying the answer is in my previous question, can you kindly explain how the indexdate and deathdate are being compared for 12months or more? because i see it being compared to currentdate - interval '1 year'??**

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate (of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322914/how-to-perform-date-calculations-from-different-tables), unless you explain why a `where` clause on the answers to those questions doesn't resolve your issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff appreicate all your help, The reason it doesnt solve is because i believe it is checking date from today and is not doing a date comparison between the 2 dates?

Comment: Also, the answer on that question is doing a min(date) check, which is not what i want?

Comment: BTW "is the difference between indexdate and deathdate >=12 months" is equal to `index_year != death_year`. Use `date_part('year', date_field)` or `extract(year from date_field)` to get the year from the date: [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). For example: `select id, chd18.age, indexdate, deathdate from chd18 join died1216 using(id) where date_part('year', indexdate) != date_part('year', deathdate);`